# Escaped Skolem with hoistCofree in Purescript

Tags: functional-programming, purescript

I'm playing in Purescript with a representation of Graphs that uses Cofree and the Algebraic Graph approach from https://hackage.haskell.org/package/algebraic-graphs (coming from https://hackage.haskell.org/package/apart-0.1.3/docs/Data-Apart-Structures-Graph.html)

```
type Graph = Cofree Edges

data Edges a = Empty | Connect a | Overlay a 

connect :: forall a. Graph a -> Graph a
connect g = hoistCofree step g
  where
    step (Empty) = Empty
    step (Connect ys) = Connect ys
    step (Overlay ys) = Connect ys
```

Unfortunately, using `hoistCofree` for instance above to fully connect an existing graph, leads to an `EscapedSkolem` error.

However, using a simpler typed hoistCofree (borrowed from https://github.com/coot/purescript-redox/blob/v7.0.1/src/Redox/Utils.purs#L27-L32):

```
hoistCofree'
  :: forall f state
   . (Functor f)
  => (f (Cofree f state) -> f (Cofree f state))
  -> Cofree f state
  -> Cofree f state
hoistCofree' nat cf = head cf :< nat (hoistCofree' nat <$> tail cf)
```

Just works.

Is there a way I can make the code work with `hoistCofree` instead?

Comment: I am not getting an error with that code, using `hoistCofree` from the `free` package on GHC 9.0.1.  Is that the `hoistCofree` you are using? What version of GHC are you using? Is that the exact code that is causing the error (same type signatures, etc)?

Comment: Sorry maybe I shouldn't have used the haskell tag! This is in purescript :) Made the title clearer.

Comment: My bet is that you need a type signature for `step` to make it polymorphic enough. This would probably also be needed in Haskell when compiling with `MonoLocalBinds` (or `GADTs` or `TypeFamilies`, which imply it).